# Как правильно задать путь к файлу

Tags: java, maven, jar, path

Собираю jar через maven и столкнулся с проблемой, а именно с путём к бинарнику phantomjs. ОС ubuntu.

```
((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", Server.class.getResource("/phantomjs").getPath());
```

Вот дерево проекта

[image: дерево проекта]

Такой путь выдает логгер:

```
INFO: executable: /home/vitaly/IdeaProjects/ValeoServer10bet/target/classes/phantomjs
```

Если запускать проект через IDE (Intellij), то все работает нормально, но если запускаю джарник через консоль - то получаю ошибку.

```
sudo java -cp /home/vitaly/IdeaProjects/ValeoServer10bet/target/ValeoServer10bet-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.valeobet.server.Server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The driver executable does not exist: /home/vitaly/file:/home/vitaly/IdeaProjects/ValeoServer10bet/target/ValeoServer10bet-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/phantomjs
```

Как правильно собрать проект, я не понимаю.. Помогите, спасибо

Comment: предположу, что executable вызывает ОС, а она внутрь вашего джарника смотреть не умеет

Comment: @Etki хммм, интересно, спасибо за наводку, буду думать